# MongoItemReader: how to deal with custom fields?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-batch

MongoItemReader provided by spring batch has method setFields:

```
public void setFields(java.lang.String fields)
JSON defining the fields to be returned from the matching documents by 
MongoDB.
Parameters:
fields - JSON string that identifies the fields to sort by.
```

I have a class:

```
public class Raw {

private String id;
private String version;
private String client;
private String appName;
private String os;
// getters & setters
}
```

And I have data in mongodb like that:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58a3373e1e041a1191cd5d6d"),
"Version" : "123",
"Client" : "SomeClient",
"MobilePlatform" : "iphoneos",
"AppName" : "MyAppName",
"Os" : "Windows 10"
}
```

- so as you can see all fields names start with capital letter.
Now I need to read data from mongo with spring batch.
And I need to map somehow fields in my Raw class to data in mongo DB so I will be able to fetch data.
I suspect that setFields method is just for such cases.
But I am relatively new to mongo and spring batch also,
so I would like to ask how to do that?
Which JSON should I put into setFields method?
Or probably there are some other options?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the anwer by myself in documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html
@Field annotation can be used and it works.